Issues loading a .ttl file into Protege on an off-line computer
I'm fairly new to using Protege and have been trying out some small test.ttl files to get practice loading a preexisting ontology model into protege but they won't load as Classes and Properties. I need to do this on a computer that runs off-line (lets call this System A).
I am using a very basic script on my on-line computer (call this System B)
@prefix : <http://example.org/demo#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://example.org/demo> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:radio rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:label "Radio" .

:capability rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:label "Capability" .

:range a owl:Class ;
       rdfs:label "Range" .


:hasColor rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:label "Has Color" ;
          rdfs:domain :radio ;
          rdfs:range rdf:literal .


:hasCapabilities rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                 rdfs:label "Has Cpabilities" ;
                 rdfs:domain :radio ;
                 rdfs:range :capability .

:hasRange a owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:label "Has Range" ;
          rdfs:domain :radio ;
          rdfs:range :range .

I have very similar one on the System A computer, which I have to manually replicate the files because I cannot load things onto System A. The script will load on System B and show the Entities populated and their object properties, however, when I load the similar file on System A the metrics say I have Axioms but they are not showing up as Entity classes or object properties.
Does anyone know how I can fix this? I know I can manually build the ontology Model on Protege, but I have a complex data model and would prefer automating this.

Without seeing the actual file it's hard to advise. I'd suggest trying an even smaller example on system a: take a copy of the file and delete everything but the first class, try and load. If it works, add the next declaration. If not,  you have the smallest example you can add here.
